# Best way to resize a data sequence in Python

Tags: python, list, sequence

I've got a data sequence (a list) that I have to resize. I've written a function for it, but its very crude. Does anyone know of a better way to solve this?

### Expected behaviour:

In all examples my input data sequence is the following:
Edit: even though the example is linear, you can't expect that the sequence is build by a formula.

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

When I resize it from 10 items to 5, I expect something like the following output:

`[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` or `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

Now all this isn't very difficult when you cut the length of the data sequence in half, but the size of my output sequence is variable. I could smaller or larger than the length of the original sequence.

When I resize it from 10 items to 19 (easy number to do manually), I expect something like this:

`[1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10]`

### Current function

```
def sequenceResize(source, length):
    """
    Crude way of resizing a data sequence.
    Shrinking is here a lot more accurate than expanding.
    """
    sourceLen = len(source)
    out = []
    for i in range(length):
        key = int(i * (sourceLen / length))
        if key >= sourceLen:
            key = sourceLen - 1

        out.append(source[key])
    return out
```

This results in the following:

```
>>> sequenceResize(sequence, 5)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> sequenceResize(sequence, 19)
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10]
```

Shrinking is accurate, but expanding the sequence is not so great.

Does anyone know of an existing, or simple way to tackle this problem properly?

Comment: I understand the expanding part: you just want a list with x elements which goes from 1 to 10 so the step is variable. What I don't get is what you expect when shrinking the list

Comment: You could take the minimum and maximum element, and randomly generate the remaining numbers from that range.  Use random.uniform(min,max) to generate float numbers.

Comment: with shrinking I would expect to go from `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` to e.g. `[1, 4, 6, 9]`

Comment: Are the numbers evenly spaced? What if you "resize" `[1,2,4,8,16]`?

Comment: @struthi sadly the actual data sequence doesn't adhere to a single equation like in the example.

Comment: @tobias no they are not. Resizing that to 3 items would give something like [1, 4, 16] but I would prefer intermediate values like [1, (8+4+2)/3, 16]

Comment: You need to interpolate. Perhaps nearest neighbor scaling if you want to keep the data discrete.

Comment: @dan that sounds good. I didn't realize that's what I'm looking for until you mentioned it :) a little Google revealed some promising scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of determining the index directly, you should calculate the ratio of "steps" between indices in both lists. Note that there is one fewer step than there are elements in the list. Then, you can get the `floor` and `ceil` item and determine the final value based on the decimal part of the current step, getting the weighted average between the two (see figure below).

```
def sequenceResize(source, length):
    step = float(len(source) - 1) / (length - 1)
    for i in range(length):
        key = i * step
        low = source[int(math.floor(key))]
        high = source[int(math.ceil(key))]
        ratio = key % 1
        yield (1 - ratio) * low + ratio * high
```

Or a bit shorter, using `divmod`:

```
def sequenceResize(source, length):
    step = float(len(source) - 1) / (length - 1)
    for i in range(length):
        low, ratio = divmod(i * step, 1)
        high = low + 1 if ratio > 0 else low
        yield (1- ratio) * source[int(low)] + ratio * source[int(high)]
```

Examples:

```
>>> sequence = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
>>> list(sequenceResize(sequence, 5))
[1, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0, 16.0]
>>> list(sequenceResize(sequence, 3))
[1, 4.0, 16.0]
>>> list(sequenceResize(sequence, 10))
[1, 1.44444, 1.88889, 2.66667, 3.55556, 4.88889, 6.66667, 8.88889, 12.44444, 16.0]
>>> list(sequenceResize(sequence, 19))
[1, 1.22222, 1.44444, 1.66667, 1.88889, 2.22222, 2.66667, 3.11111, 3.55556, 4.0, 4.88889, 5.77778, 6.66667, 7.55556, 8.88889, 10.66667, 12.44444, 14.22222, 16.0]
```

A different example as an illustration. Blue are the original values, and red the interpolated ones.

[image]

Comment: This worked great for me! Thanks, Tobias :) The only thing I added is `if key > len(source) - 1: key = len(source) - 1` because, with length = 500, the last key could be `499.000000001`

Comment: @Lakitna For that exact reason I had something like `key = round(i * step, 5)` in an earlier version (see edit history), but in later tests it seemed not to be necessary any more. But yours should work as well.

Comment: It happens when you try to expand a sequence by a lot. Probably some rounding python does that stacks every iteration. Your rounding solution is a lot more elegant than my solution, so I'll swap it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use np.lisnpace:

```
import numpy as np

list_in = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

resize = 19

list_out = np.linspace(list_in[0], list_in[-1], num=resize)

print(np.ndarray.tolist(list_out))
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0]
```

Comment: Can you update your answer with the contents of the output?

Comment: Sounds good, but does it also work if the sequence isnt a single formula, linear or otherwise?

Comment: @Lakitna no, only interpolate between first and last values of list_in.